# Что указывать в переменной $accountId php-sdk moneta.ru?

Tags: php, sdk, платежи

Подключаю платежную систему Payanyway (moneta.ru) к сайту https://bestparser.000webhostapp.com/ . Прилагается описание php-sdk от moneta.ru - https://payanyway.ru/info/p/ru/public/merchants/SDKphp.pdf . В нем на странице 16 описывается, как сделать отображение остатков счета пользователя:

`$monetaSDK = new Moneta\MonetaSdk(); $result = $monetaSDK->showAccountBalance($accountId); echo $result->render;`

Где переменная $accountId - номер счета нового пользователя. Вопрос: что указывать в этой переменной, какой именно номер? Где его взять или посмотреть/получить? Указывая любое произвольное число, выдает ошибку "Ошибка авторизации...". Где достать этот самый $accountId? В описании sdk этого нет.

Comment: На странице 15 написано.

Comment: Там только про авторизацию, про получение данных ни слова...